# Compiling with Python 3.3

Tags: python, command-line, cx-freeze

Let me start by saying I have only very recently started programming. I don't know how to use the cx_freeze script. I don't know how to make the word 'python' work in commandline. I am just looking for complete and detailed directions on how to make a .py file into a .exe file that can work without Python. I haven't had luck with cx_freeze and nothing else seems to work with 3.3. Can anyone tell me wher to start?

Comment: I'm sorry to say such a process is quite complicated, and if you can't get the word 'python' working in the command line, your chances of success on this are very low. Is there some other solution? what is your specific problem that has called for a solution such as this?

Comment: To get the command `python` to work from the command line, you need to learn more about your OS (apparently Windows). This is not python-specific. You can then apply that knowledge (with some additional help) to installing and using other programs, such as `cx_freeze`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, cx_freeze is the only way to do it as far as I can tell.

Perhaps you are just having bad luck with cx_freeze. Try this in a .bat file.

```
@echo off
<python path>\python <python path>\scripts\cxfreeze <script .py file>
exit
```

Python path is most likely C:\python33.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but what exactly do you mean by try it in a .bat file? I don't know how or where I would begin doing that.

Comment: A .bat (batch) file is a series of commands that Windows can run. As others have said, you probably need to get a bit more comfortable with Python and the command line before you can make this work.

Comment: @user2009338 If you don't know what a bat file is, perhaps you should learn a bit more about Windows and Python. A .bat is a text file that contains commands like "echo" and "type" and stuff. If you've ever used the Windows CMD, it's a series of CMD commands.