# Compile pygame - python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, pygame

I'm trying to compile a Tetris type game using pygame in python 3.3. The program uses various folders and modules. I've tried using CX_FREEZE, so far it hasn't seemed to work. If someone would be able to tell me how to compile this i would be forever grateful

Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512936/compiling-with-python-3-3), but the answer (as posted in that question) was this:

```
Unfortunately, cx_freeze is the only way to do it as far as I can tell.
```

Perhaps you are just having bad luck with cx_freeze. Try this in a .bat file.

```
@echo off
<python path>\python <python path>\scripts\cxfreeze <script .py file>
exit
```

Your Python path is most likely C:\python33.

.

just make a .bat file (a batch file), then put the code from the other answer in it. A batch file is a file containing a series of commands that Windows can run as if from command line. Do not forget to change

```
\python <python path>\
```

to your correct python path.